# cant play movie file with JME3-JFX

Tags: javafx, mp4, flv, jmonkeyengine

I am trying to play an flv file using [JME3X-JFX](https://github.com/empirephoenix/JME3-JFX) and i use the [demo class](https://github.com/empirephoenix/JME3-JFX/blob/master/src/test/java/com/jme3x/jfx/TestMovie.java) and can play [their file](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/javafx/oow2010-2.flv) via the http url method. I can also download their flv and play it with the flv method. But i cant seem to play my own flv file (downloaded after using a site eg. [keepvid](http://www.keepvid.com) (have tried a couple) to convert from a youtube video url (open license)).

It kindof sounds similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20597998/javafx-video-not-playing), where only black screen shows, but for me, the videos sound plays. I have tried using [RichFLV](http://richapps.de/richflv-apollo-flv-editing-tool/) to edit metadata to be similar to that of the demo video that works.

Also, my video im trying to play is at least half the file size of their file (when downloaded) on disk.

Also, most avis will not play for me either as i get a doesnt support YCbCr_422 which i think might be the apple version of mp4. I dont require mp4 but i need at least one type to work.

Back to the FLV.
I simply swap the line:

```
final Media media = new Media("file:////Users/juliusskye/Desktop/FYPI/simplevoicehud/assets/Video/test.flv");
```

(which is their video rename to test), to

```
final Media media = new Media("file:////Users/juliusskye/Desktop/FYPI/simplevoicehud/assets/Video/myvideo.flv");
```

and the difference is, the working version (their video) resizes but mine doesnt.

**========
working
=========**

```
Oct 23, 2015 6:04:02 PM com.jme3.system.JmeDesktopSystem initialize
INFO: Running on jMonkeyEngine 3.0.10
Oct 23, 2015 6:04:02 PM com.jme3.system.Natives extractNativeLibs
INFO: Extraction Directory: /Users/juliusskye/Desktop/FYPI/simplevoicehud
Oct 23, 2015 6:04:02 PM com.jme3.system.lwjgl.LwjglContext printContextInitInfo
INFO: Lwjgl 2.9.0 context running on thread LWJGL Renderer Thread
Oct 23, 2015 6:04:02 PM com.jme3.system.lwjgl.LwjglContext printContextInitInfo
INFO: Adapter: null
Oct 23, 2015 6:04:02 PM com.jme3.system.lwjgl.LwjglContext printContextInitInfo
INFO: Driver Version: null
Oct 23, 2015 6:04:02 PM com.jme3.system.lwjgl.LwjglContext printContextInitInfo
INFO: Vendor: Intel Inc.
Oct 23, 2015 6:04:02 PM com.jme3.system.lwjgl.LwjglContext printContextInitInfo
INFO: OpenGL Version: 2.1 INTEL-8.24.16
Oct 23, 2015 6:04:02 PM com.jme3.system.lwjgl.LwjglContext printContextInitInfo
INFO: Renderer: Intel HD Graphics 3000 OpenGL Engine
Oct 23, 2015 6:04:02 PM com.jme3.system.lwjgl.LwjglContext printContextInitInfo
INFO: GLSL Ver: 1.20
2015-10-23 18:04:03.855 java[45029:ae17] Error loading /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL/Digidesign CoreAudio.plugin/Contents/MacOS/Digidesign CoreAudio:  dlopen(/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL/Digidesign CoreAudio.plugin/Contents/MacOS/Digidesign CoreAudio, 262): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL/Digidesign CoreAudio.plugin/Contents/MacOS/Digidesign CoreAudio: no matching architecture in universal wrapper
2015-10-23 18:04:03.857 java[45029:ae17] Cannot find function pointer NewDigiCoreAudioPlugIn for factory B8A063B5-2F3D-444A-88CB-D0B8F1B22042 in CFBundle/CFPlugIn 0x7fb20bc51a40 </Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL/Digidesign CoreAudio.plugin> (bundle, not loaded)
Oct 23, 2015 6:04:03 PM com.jme3.audio.lwjgl.LwjglAudioRenderer initInThread
INFO: Audio Device: OpenAL Soft
Oct 23, 2015 6:04:03 PM com.jme3.audio.lwjgl.LwjglAudioRenderer initInThread
INFO: Audio Vendor: OpenAL Community
Oct 23, 2015 6:04:03 PM com.jme3.audio.lwjgl.LwjglAudioRenderer initInThread
INFO: Audio Renderer: OpenAL Soft
Oct 23, 2015 6:04:03 PM com.jme3.audio.lwjgl.LwjglAudioRenderer initInThread
INFO: Audio Version: 1.1 ALSOFT 1.15.1
Oct 23, 2015 6:04:03 PM com.jme3.audio.lwjgl.LwjglAudioRenderer initInThread
INFO: AudioRenderer supports 64 channels
Oct 23, 2015 6:04:03 PM com.jme3.audio.lwjgl.LwjglAudioRenderer initInThread
INFO: Audio effect extension version: 1.0
Oct 23, 2015 6:04:03 PM com.jme3.audio.lwjgl.LwjglAudioRenderer initInThread
INFO: Audio max auxilary sends: 4
resize : 540 x 540
```

**============
not working
==============**

```
Oct 23, 2015 6:03:02 PM com.jme3.system.JmeDesktopSystem initialize
INFO: Running on jMonkeyEngine 3.0.10
Oct 23, 2015 6:03:03 PM com.jme3.system.Natives extractNativeLibs
INFO: Extraction Directory: /Users/juliusskye/Desktop/FYPI/simplevoicehud
Oct 23, 2015 6:03:03 PM com.jme3.system.lwjgl.LwjglContext printContextInitInfo
INFO: Lwjgl 2.9.0 context running on thread LWJGL Renderer Thread
Oct 23, 2015 6:03:03 PM com.jme3.system.lwjgl.LwjglContext printContextInitInfo
INFO: Adapter: null
Oct 23, 2015 6:03:03 PM com.jme3.system.lwjgl.LwjglContext printContextInitInfo
INFO: Driver Version: null
Oct 23, 2015 6:03:03 PM com.jme3.system.lwjgl.LwjglContext printContextInitInfo
INFO: Vendor: Intel Inc.
Oct 23, 2015 6:03:03 PM com.jme3.system.lwjgl.LwjglContext printContextInitInfo
INFO: OpenGL Version: 2.1 INTEL-8.24.16
Oct 23, 2015 6:03:03 PM com.jme3.system.lwjgl.LwjglContext printContextInitInfo
INFO: Renderer: Intel HD Graphics 3000 OpenGL Engine
Oct 23, 2015 6:03:03 PM com.jme3.system.lwjgl.LwjglContext printContextInitInfo
INFO: GLSL Ver: 1.20
2015-10-23 18:03:04.350 java[44916:d107] Error loading /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL/Digidesign CoreAudio.plugin/Contents/MacOS/Digidesign CoreAudio:  dlopen(/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL/Digidesign CoreAudio.plugin/Contents/MacOS/Digidesign CoreAudio, 262): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL/Digidesign CoreAudio.plugin/Contents/MacOS/Digidesign CoreAudio: no matching architecture in universal wrapper
2015-10-23 18:03:04.352 java[44916:d107] Cannot find function pointer NewDigiCoreAudioPlugIn for factory B8A063B5-2F3D-444A-88CB-D0B8F1B22042 in CFBundle/CFPlugIn 0x7f9d025d6fa0 </Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL/Digidesign CoreAudio.plugin> (bundle, not loaded)
Oct 23, 2015 6:03:04 PM com.jme3.audio.lwjgl.LwjglAudioRenderer initInThread
INFO: Audio Device: OpenAL Soft
Oct 23, 2015 6:03:04 PM com.jme3.audio.lwjgl.LwjglAudioRenderer initInThread
INFO: Audio Vendor: OpenAL Community
Oct 23, 2015 6:03:04 PM com.jme3.audio.lwjgl.LwjglAudioRenderer initInThread
INFO: Audio Renderer: OpenAL Soft
Oct 23, 2015 6:03:04 PM com.jme3.audio.lwjgl.LwjglAudioRenderer initInThread
INFO: Audio Version: 1.1 ALSOFT 1.15.1
Oct 23, 2015 6:03:04 PM com.jme3.audio.lwjgl.LwjglAudioRenderer initInThread
INFO: AudioRenderer supports 64 channels
Oct 23, 2015 6:03:04 PM com.jme3.audio.lwjgl.LwjglAudioRenderer initInThread
INFO: Audio effect extension version: 1.0
Oct 23, 2015 6:03:04 PM com.jme3.audio.lwjgl.LwjglAudioRenderer initInThread
INFO: Audio max auxilary sends: 4
```

Comment: from what ive gathered, it seems the JavaFX library only supports flv's encoded with VP6 codec, which there is seemingly no mac support for. but there must be some web servce for encoding in this kind.

https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/package-summary.html

http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/vp6-codec-im-out-of-luck-arent-i.81314/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the JavaFX library only supports flv's encoded with VP6 codec, which there is very few programs supporting conversion.

http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/vp6-codec-im-out-of-luck-arent-i.81314/
https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/package-summary.html

I was able to download a trial of Sorenson Squeeze that allows conversion to VP6 on a mac.
encoding.com seems to also offer the conversion as a service.

Comment: So once you converted the FLV to VP6 encoding, playback using JavaFX (and no other additional installed software) on the Mac worked fine right?  So JavaFX on the Mac actually does support playback of VP6 encoded FLVs?

Comment: yes that is correct. my answer was badly worded copypaste of comment. have reworded it.