# Not playing video in mediaPlayer javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I have problem with showing video in JavaFx Media:

```
public void showVideo(File videoFile) {
    scrollPane.setHvalue(scrollPane.getHmin());
    scrollPane.setVvalue(scrollPane.getVmin());

    Media media = new Media("http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/javafx/oow2010-2.flv");
    final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
    final MediaView mediaContent = new MediaView(mediaPlayer);

    HBox menuBox = new HBox();
    menuBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    menuBox.getChildren().addAll(playButton, stopButton);
    VBox videoBox = new VBox();
    videoBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    videoBox.getChildren().addAll(mediaContent, menuBox);

    playButtonListener(mediaPlayer);
    stopButtonListener(mediaPlayer);

    mediaPlayer.setOnEndOfMedia(new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {
            playButton.setGraphic(WindowUtil.createIcon(IconsConstants.ICON_PLAYER_REPEAT));
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            playButtonListener(mediaPlayer);
        }
    });

    scrollPane.setContent(videoBox);
}
```

I know that the code isn't wrong because in my coworker system it shows.
I try to show flv file.
I saw question:
[JavaFX video not playing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20597998/javafx-video-not-playing)

I have windows 10 N with K-Lite standart codec and jdk-8u65-windows-x64 Java and I installed feature pack for windows 10 like in link above.
And I don't know what can be the problem.

Comment: JavaFX supports FLV-Files containing VP6 video and MP3 audio. Maybe the file you trying to play does not match the requirements?

Comment: I edited how it works in my coworker system (but not mine) in Media constructor by giving link. The same link.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, problem solved. I update feature pack and now it's working. Probably previous version of feature pack for windows 10 N doesn't have codecs which I need.